# When to give up on Permutation and Combination and use Tree Diagram.

Tags: probability-theory

**Question:**
When to give up on Permutation and Combination and use Tree Diagram. I need a good heuristics for determining this sort of problem. Such heuristics will be valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with tree diagrams is that if you have anything more than 100 options you don't want to draw all of them, and if you use any sort of shortcuts then you're basically just using other enumerative techniques anyway so you might as well omit the tree diagram.

So to me the question is backwards: When there are too many options (for me, "too many" is about 12) then I give up on tree diagrams and use permutations and combinations :)